# Mongos saves data to wrong shard

Tags: mongodb

I am seeing some odd behavior and am hoping some light would be shed to help me see if this is somethign I am doign wrong, or if its a known issue with mongo.

In a nutshell, we noticed that all docs from a collection went missing one day. Upon further investigation, it seemed that while the database was homed to a single shard (1), the database and the "missing" collection (with the data in it) appeared on another shard (2). In our setup we have a sharded/replicated cluster with 3 config servers.

Via sh.status() I can see that a db of interest is homed to a particular shard:

```
    sh.status()
    ...
    {  "_id" : "myDB123",  "partitioned" : false,  "primary" : "rs_shard1" }
```

When I go to that shard's primary and check the count of the colletion, it is empty:

```
rs_shard1:PRIMARY> db.myCollection.count()
0
```

However, if I go to the second shard (where this DB should not exist) i see the following:

```
rs_shard2:PRIMARY> use myDB123
switched to db myDB123
rs_shard2:PRIMARY> show collections
myCollection
system.indexes
rs_shard2:PRIMARY> db.myCollection.count()
153
```

I have seen this behavior on 2.2.2 and 2.4.4. I know that there are alot of complications behind the scenes for Mongo given a sharded/replicated cluster, so I am wondering if this is known issue and/or if anyone else has seen this behavior? If so, any insight as to what causes this?

Thanks again!

Comment: Could you provide some more info?like the shard key and the structure of the docs in the collection?

Comment: Hi Scrooj, the collection was not sharded (thus no shard key and my confusion). Given that, I dont think the doc structure would be relevant, but either way its rather simple: {
 "_id" : ObjectId("MYOBJECTID"),
 "productId" : "9500",
 "productURL" : "www.myproductsurl.com",
 "schemaVersion" : 2,
 "createTime" : NumberLong("123"),
 "lastUpdateTime" : NumberLong("456"),
 "graphId" : "graphId123",
 "crawlId" : "crawlId456", 
}

Thanks again for the time.

Comment: Are you saying that the collection appearing on a shard that is not marked as primary is the **whole** collection, or just a set of writes that happened at a particular time. And you also have no [movePrimary](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/movePrimary/) commands in any admin scripts.

Comment: It seems like the entire collection (as well as other collections actually) also existed on the shard. I am pretty confident there were not any scripts using the movePrimary command. I understand, and appologize, for the lack of details;I know it doesnt help try to figure out whats wrong. Have you experienced or heard from others about mongos' pointing to different shards after some time? Given that other collections existed there too, it seems like its possible it completely swapped its home shard.